# Is it possible to find UNSATisfiable solutions to a SAT problem with a SAT problem?

Tags: problem-solving, sat

I'm working with several problems, which can have special unsatisfiable configurations.
For example, consider the simple function $f(x,y)=x+y+2$ with $n$-bit unsigned inputs and $(n+2)$-bit unsigned output. This function can be easily expressed as a SAT problem.

Note, that the outputs $f(x,y)=0$ and $f(x,y)=1$ are not possible.

For my problems, I'm specifically interested in such impossible configurations. The usual method for finding such configurations, is to try possible configurations and check if they are UNSAT instances. However, this has the obvious drawback, that it is computational intensive (for my problems confirming UNSAT is much more expensive than finding SAT solutions) and relies on a certain density of the impossible configurations in the problem space (or external knowledge to narrow down the possible candidates).

This leads to my question:
Is there some way to reformulate/convert/transform a SAT problem, of the form as described above into another SAT problem, where the satisfiable solutions are the impossible configurations I'm interested in?

Intuitively it should be possible, but all ways I could come up with, will simply output impossible solutions like $x=1, y=1, f(x,y)=3$.

Some paper searches also did not turn up anything useful.

Does anyone have ideas or pointers how to tackle this problem?
Also, any pointers to impossibility results that show this approach is not feasible are welcome.

Comment: A general method like this would prove NP equals coNP, no? This is a major open problem. On the more practical side, did you try throwing your problem at a SAT solver? In my experience (which is not necessarily with a very varied type of input) they are quite good with both positive and negative instances.

Comment: I'm not sure about the NP equals coNP, as this might be a special instance. Regarding simply using a SAT solver: the problem is, that I need to instantiate all possible outcomes as separate instances and solve each one. If the output space is large, this is infeasible or at least has a low success probability for finding an UNSAT instance.

Comment: Are you asking for a technique that (sometimes) lets you go down from $\Sigma_2$ of the polynomial hierarchy to $\Sigma_1$ by somehow inverting the last quantifier? Or am I completely off? I know that there's some research into higher levels of the hierarchy, but I don't know how practical this is (a funny method I heard about, dunno how well it works, is to feed a SAT solver into a SAT solver...).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the polynomial hierarchy, but the example you mention with a SAT solver solving a SAT solver  ( $solver(solverSAT(problem)==UNSAT)$ ) would be a solution to my problem (even if it does not sound very feasible...).

Comment: NP = $\Sigma_1$ = languages like $\{u \;|\; \exists v: P(u, v)\}$, and $\Sigma_2$ is languages like $\{u \;|\; \exists v: \forall w: P(u, v, w)\}$ for some polynomially checkable predicates.

Comment: Now, it sounds like you have some predicate $P$ you are interested in, and you want to know whether there exists a word $u$ such that for all $v$, the statement $P(u, v)$ holds. Here $u$ is the problem parameters, and $v$ is a witness proving the parameters are bad. This is the same as asking whether $P$ is in the language $\{p \;|\; \exists u: \forall v: p(u, v)\}$ so it's a $\Sigma_2$ type problem.

Comment: Specifically, I think you are asking if there is a trick (possibly when we are interested only in $p$ of special form) to turn the $v$-quantification around, to get an equivalence with a problem of the form $\{p \;|\; \exists u: \exists v: p(u, v)\}$, since that's an NP problem and you could use a SAT solver.

Comment: I tried to express the two problems in these terms. $p^+$ is the original SAT problem and $p^-$ is the problem I'm looking for. $\{p^+~|~\exists u : \exists v : p^+(u,v)\}$ with $p^+(u,v) \equiv f(v.1,v.2) = u$ and $\{p^-~|~\exists u : \forall v : p^-(u,v)\}$ with $p^-(u,v) \equiv f(v.1,v.2) \neq u$ where $v$ is an encoding of the two inputs and $u$ is an encoding of the output. I'm not sure, if this helps, but it would be my first approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136932/discussion-between-dasarchive-and-ville-salo).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is most likely not possible to find a polynomial-size propositional formula whose models are exactly the non-outputs of $f(x,y)$, the problem for general $f$ is $\Sigma_2^p$-complete. You probably need to express your problem as a quantified Boolean formula (QBF) of the form $\exists z \; \forall x, y \; f(x, y) \neq z$. If you already have a formula encoding $f(x, y) = z$, you could just add the negated quantifiers $\forall z \; \exists x, y \; f(x, y) = z$, and check with a QBF solver that it is false; there are quite a few good ones out there, and they will also give you a witness of falsity, in this case a value for $z$.

I recommend to take a look at the input formats [QDIMACS](https://www.qbflib.org/qdimacs.html) and the more flexible [QCIR](https://www.qbflib.org/qcir.pdf). For solvers, try [Cadet](https://markusrabe.github.io/cadet/), [DepQBF](http://lonsing.github.io/depqbf/), or [CaQE](https://www.react.uni-saarland.de/tools/caqe/) (QDIMACS input), [QuAbs](https://github.com/ltentrup/quabs), or [Qfun](http://sat.inesc-id.pt/%7Emikolas/sw/qfun/) (QCIR input), or [Qute](https://github.com/fslivovsky/qute) (both inputs; disclaimer, I'm one of the co-authors of Qute).